# Word/phrase for parent whose children have grown up and left home

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, kinship-terms

Is there a single word or phrase that means a parent whose grown-up children are not living with them?

Comment: There's SKIers - Spending Kids' Inheritance.

Comment: @BarrieEngland Is it a slang? I couldn't find it in dictionaries. Would you please expand a bit on S.K.I.? I'm very interested in that expression.

Comment: I'm not surprised you couldn't find it. I've only heard it occsionally and I don't suppose it will last. These acronyms come and go. At the moment we hear quite a lot about young people who are NEETs - Not In Employment, Education or Training. I think your Empty Nester meets the case better, so +1 for that.

Comment: Voted to re-open. This is a single word or phrase request ("what's a word/phrase for X?"), not asking the definition of a word ("what does X mean?"). The first answer below may link to a dictionary but, without knowing the term, I would not have been able to find it.

Comment: @Hugo: [bet you could have...](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+parent+whose+children+have+all+grown+up+and+left+home)

Comment: I disagree that this was a "general reference" question. In fact, I don't think it's a proper question *at all* - finding the answer is beyond trivial, the idea that even the most preliminary research was conducted defies belief. The question is [a poster-child for questions that seem to exist purely to solve crosswords](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity) - and the answer bears this out, adding nothing to the definition it links to.

Comment: @Shog9, ironically, today this very page appears higher in those search results than the dictionary definition cited below.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**[Empty nester](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/empty+nester)** might be of your interest, although it's not that formal.

Comment: @drɱ65δ We might as well coin some words that would imitate the analogy here :)